# Let the Next Privilege point to the Privilege page on Mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, privileges

When clicking on the `Next Privilege` progress bar in the web site, you see a tip telling you what you can achieve.

[image: web]

However, showing the tip was disabled on the mobile website for obvious reasons (it is breaking layout now):

[image: mobile web]

Clicking the progress bar does nothing.

I would love to see the mobile website progress bar point to the same source the `Learn More` button does on the normal website: the [next privilege's info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (moderator tools in my case).