# Make the next badge tracker a clickable link on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web

This feature request is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253935/let-the-next-privilege-point-to-the-privilege-page-on-mobile), but is about a different progress tracker.

On your profile, there's a next badge tracker.  On the desktop site, this is clickable, and it shows you what to do to earn the badge:

[image: desktop screenshot]

On the mobile site, the badge tracker is there, but there's no clickability.

[image: mobile screenshot]

There's no quick way to find out what you have to do to earn the badge, you have to click to the badges page and find in page to get to it.  I request that this is made clickable.  It should either link to the badge page for that badge, or an overlay could appear like the desktop site.